# GeoPDF from FME not recognised in QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, fme-form, import, pdf

I tried to creat a simple **GeoPDF** in **FME**. As input in contains just orto + some vector objects.
When I open it in AcrobatReader I can see both vector and raster, I am able to check attributes etc.
I tried to re-open it in **QGIS** 3.18 and it says it is invalid data. Both if I try to drag&drop or Add Vector/Raster layers...

I used same data inside QGIS and was able to create GeoPDF. It was still possible to reimport both raster and vector to QGIS.

QGIS is main software in company but unfortunatelly i can't make a workflow that is based on QGIS.

Will be glad for any suggestions! I attatch workflow so it will be easier to undestand
[image: Workflow]

Comment: Think you need the PDFStyler first before writing see https://community.safe.com/s/article/creating-pdf-cartographic-output

Comment: Well I was able to create a PDF with data I wanted. 
Styler is used  (as far as I understand it) to create a layout with title, and annotations + display settings... Anyway - I tried both ways and still it is not possible to reload it to QGIS.

Comment: Please post your answer - you will be able to accept your own answer after a time interval.

Comment: When you say "GeoPDF" do you mean that in a generic way or the specific GeoPDF format (by TerraGo)? FME creates "GeoSpatial PDF" - the OGC/Adobe version - but not TerraGo GeoPDFs. I just want to be clear on the expectation here.

Comment: @MarkIreland - I mean GeoSpatial PDF in OGC standard :)

Comment: I think you'll have to contact the support team at Safe and send them the PDF. I can't imagine why it wouldn't open and I don't see any other reports of that behaviour. I assume it opens OK in Adobe Viewer/Acrobat?

Comment: You have to check the "PDF 1.4 Compatible" option in the FME Edit Parameters dialog for an FME-created geospatial PDF to display in QGIS.

Comment: That worked! thanks @RudyStricklan

Comment: Thanks @Lynx. Could you mark my comment as the answer? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry @RudyStricklan I can't... or rather - I don't know how to... and even I googled it doesn't help much...